Add rows to a datatable
I have been working on a lighting data table and have now been able to edit the data table values and when saving create new records.
My question is, can you add a row to a data table?
I read where you can add actions to the row but I do not see an add action, just delete and edit.
This is what I have
picklist column html
<template>
    <lightning-combobox 
        name="picklist" 
        data-inputable="true" 
        label={typeAttributes.label} 
        value={typeAttributes.value} 
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} 
        options={typeAttributes.options} 
        style="width:300px;"
        variant='label-hidden'>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>

Picklist JS
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import picklistColumn from './picklistColumn.html';
import pickliststatic from './pickliststatic.html'

export default class CustomDatatablePicklist extends LightningDatatable {
    
    static customTypes = {
        picklistColumn: {
            template: pickliststatic,
            editTemplate: picklistColumn,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant','name']
        }
    };
}

Main HTML
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Cost__c.Type__c';

<template>
    <lightning-card title={title}>
      
        <lightning-button-group slot="actions">
            <lightning-button label="Add Row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={handleAddRow}>
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-button-group>
        <c-custom-datatable-picklist
            key-field="Id"
            data={ceiList} 
            onsave={handleSave}
            draft-values={updatedRecords}
            columns={columns}>
        </c-custom-datatable-picklist>
     
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Main JS
const COLS = [
    {
        label: 'New Cost Type', fieldName: 'Type__c', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, 
        typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', 
            options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' }, 
            value: { fieldName: 'Type__c' },
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } 
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Per Crew',
        fieldName: 'Per_Crew__c',
        type: 'number',
        editable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Crew Members',
        fieldName: 'Crew_Members__c',
        type: 'number',
        editable: true
    }
]

 @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId", fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        console.log('picklist data ',data);
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            console.log(' this.pickListOptions ', this.pickListOptions);
            this.fetchItemRecords();
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

handleAddRow() {

        const newRow = {
            Id: '',
            Cost_Type__c: this.pickListOptions,
            Per_Crew__c:'',
            Crew_Members__c:'',
        };

        // Add the new row to the data array
        this.tableData = [...this.tableData, newRow];

I do not need to run fetchItemRecords since I am not trying to get the existing records, just need to populate picklist values.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you

The controls are usually located inside a card, like this:
<lightning-card>
  <lightning-button-group slot="actions">
   <lightning-button label="Add Row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addRow}>
   </lightning-button>
  </lightning-button-group>
  <lightning-table ...></lightning-table>
</lightning-card>

Where addRow typically looks like:
this.data = [...this.data, {}];

The {} is a placeholder; you may want to set default field values, etc here.

Thank you for the response @sddcfox.  I added some of my code for more context.  Is there a way for me to populate the column with picklist values?

I tried adding the the new row but it is not rendering.  I can see the new row in the console log but table never shows new row.

any thoughts why I can see the new row information(columns) but it never renders on the data table?

@Phuc Your table appears to be mapped to {ceiList} but you're saving to tableData.
